# MySQL Return Results Similar to String Input but Without Periods

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have something in the database under the region column named "St. Catharines"

I would like to return the records containing "St. Catharines" from a string without the period. So, the string would be "St Catharines". Can this be done? How?

Right now I have:

```
$region = "St Catharines"; 
$query = " AND region like '" . $region . "%'";
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

The period would always be absent from the `$region` string and could be anywhere within the database record (i.e. not just after "St").

Comment: Is it only the periods you want to work around, or is your need more complex (like eliminating all punctuation)?

Comment: Save a normalized version [i.e. stripped of chars you don't like] of the region in the table as well, and search over it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, just periods.

Comment: @landland Then see my comment below bestprogrammerintheworld's answer. It will be slow, but will do the job.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks Michael, but after some thought I decided to go the way of moonwave99's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I exactly follow you, but something like might work:

```
$region = "St. Catharines"; 
$query = " AND region like REPLACE($region, '.', '')"
```

Anyway I think you should use MySQL built-in-functions (string manipulation) do achieve this. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Other way around actually - `REPLACE(region, '.', '') LIKE '$region%'` the variable _doesn't_ have the period.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld $region string won't ever have periods in it.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't do that, it's not good, that should be fixed before hand.

You can split the string by spaces (using explode), and search for example the two parts:
Like a: `$arr = explode(" ",$string);`

`$query = " AND (region LIKE '".$arr[0]."%' OR '%".$arr[1]."%')";`

This would find as a result everything with "St" in the beginning and everything that contained "Catharines" in the result.

That is the best solution to that problem, is partial matching, while it might show more results then the ones you want, another solution is something like mentioned here: [stackoverflow question about removing commas and etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351377/1306385)

Comment: hmmm ok, maybe I need to rethink this. I didn't know it would be so tricky in sql