# Mysql: How to trim and compare database fields with alphanumeric values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

My site has got a search box. I've a database field value like: "Pet's name is Jimmy". I need to fetch that row when somebody searches like: "Pets name" also. Is there any way to compare only the alphanumeric values in mysql `WHERE` condition? That is both **"Pet's name"** and **"Pets name"** should return the same row. That is the comparison need to be something like : "petsname = petsname". Only alphanumeric characters are compared.

I've tried mysql **`REPLACE`** for replacing `"'"`, but I strongly believe that there exists a much better solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring apostrophes in mysql searches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351337/ignoring-apostrophes-in-mysql-searches)

Comment: Not only apostrophes, I need to avoid all special characters without using mysql "REPLACE". That is the comparison need to be something like : "petsname = petsname". Only alphanumeric characters are compared.

Comment: Update your post with that info! And read further down the page about `SOUNDEX`

Comment: Why can't you use MySQL `replace`?

Comment: Have you considered a [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)? `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE match (somefield) against ('"pet\'s name"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Comment: If I use MySQL `replace`, then I've to add all special characters in query.

Comment: MySQL does have a limited [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) that could be used here (you'd have to use PHP to create the search term): `SELECT field REGEXP '^pet[\']?s name';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Pet's name is Jimmy";

$str1  = addslashes($str);  // Outputs: Pets name is Jimmy
```

you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM pet  WHERE name like '%$str1%';
```

Comment: Please go through the question again, it's about mysql 'WHERE' condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to return the same row when someone searches like "Pets" also instead of "Pet's".

Comment: if you want to remove special charecters and search please try this `$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/', '', $str;` // Remove all characters except A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dots, hyphens and spaces

Comment: I need to avoid all special characters. That is the comparison need to be something like : "petsname = petsname". Only alphanumeric characters are compared. Please note that the special characters exists in database field.

Comment: Update your post with that info!

Comment: Updated. Please check.