# Ignore apostrophes when querying database - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, querying

I have a search bar with autocomplete on my site where users can search travel guides. *Some* of the travel guides have a name like for example: *Snookie's Outfitter* As you can see, it has a apostrophe in its name. So when a user types out the first word and hits that apostrophe, the query ignores the rest because the user didn't insert a apostrophe in the search bar. I was wondering how could I possibly ignore that apostrophe in the database.

This is how my query is set up when someone searches:

```
public function index()
    {
        $query = request()->get('query');

        $results = Listing::searchAndCache($query);

        return view('search.index', compact('results', 'query'));
    }
```

My Listing Model:

```
  public static function searchAndCache($query)
    {
        return self::whereHas('locations', function($m) use($query) {
            $m->where('region', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
            $m->orWhere('country', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
            $m->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
            $m->orWhere('county', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
            $m->orWhere('regionCode', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        })->live()->orWhere(function($m) use($query){
            $m->where('name','like','%'.$query.'%');
            $m->live();
        })->paginate();
    }
```

I know this has been asked before, particularly for PHP, but I just don't know how I would implement this in a Laravel search query.

Comment: just use HTML::entities() to encode query, which is also safer way to do anyway to protect your query against injections.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with SQL? I'm pretty good at turning SQL into Laravel syntax. I'm not that good with SQL.

Comment: I found something on this link, but they are using regular php syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351337/ignoring-apostrophes-in-mysql-searches

Comment: @guyfawkes, where exactly would I use that, around the input? or inside the function where Im getting the request

Comment: it should be before return self::whereHas... part. Added full code as answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HTML::entities() to encode your query sq quotes and double-quotes will be replaced with html references.

```
public static function searchAndCache($query)
{
    $query = HTML::entities($query);

    return self::whereHas('locations', function($m) use($query) {
        $m->where('region', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        $m->orWhere('country', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        $m->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        $m->orWhere('county', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        $m->orWhere('regionCode', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->live()->orWhere(function($m) use($query){
        $m->where('name','like','%'.$query.'%');
        $m->live();
    })->paginate();
}
```